# in c++ how to loop an array in return statement

Tags: c++, arrays, azure-functions

```cpp
public async Task < IActionResult > Events(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest httpRequest,
        ILogger log) {
        ValidateResponse res = eventService.ValidateSchema();

        if (res.Valid == false && res.Errors != null) {
            string[] messages = new string[100];
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < res.Errors.Count; i++) {
                string value = res.Errors[i].ToString();
                if (value.StartsWith("Invalid type")) {
                    messages[k++] = value.Substring(10);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return new OkObjectResult($ "No of events posted {cloudEvents.Count} and errors :{messages[k]}");
        }
```

But the values in messages are not returned. I understand that its an array . But unable to figure out the ways to loop here in return all array values once.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What are you trying to return?

Comment: I need to those values of errors .I am trying to return an array in OkObjectResult as per the requirement.

Comment: This doesn't look like C++, but like C#. I'm confused. Also you never change `k` as far as I see, so you always overwrite the first value. In C# you would use a `List<string> messages;` and `messages.Add(...)`.

Comment: Its k++ corrected in the code

Comment: Your "correction" still has not produced valid C++ code.

Comment: I am new to coding.Can anyone make corrections if its not valid c++ code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once option is to join the `messages` array to a string:

```
return new OkObjectResult($"No of events posted {cloudEvents.Count} and errors:{String.join(\",\", messages}");
```

Comment: return new OkObjectResult($"No of events posted {cloudEvents.Count} and errors:{string.Join(",", messages)}") .It is showing as invalid syntax if I use \ in the join.so I used , as seperator here but as I used string[] messages = new string[100]; It is returning 100 commas as well. can I make this messages as list. If yes how can I do this piece of code with list  messages[k] = value.Substring(10); as the array size is fixed